# From an array of data items how to group, create and collect other, key specific data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping, reduce, key-value

I have an array of objects that looks like below

```
var FinalArray = [
{"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"123"},"name":"bene","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
{"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"456"},"name":"leg","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
{"jArray":[{"Cd":"B"}],"Ref":{"docId":"123"},"name":"bene","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
{"jArray":[{"Cd":"B"}],"Ref":{"docId":"456"},"name":"leg","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
{"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"789"},"name":"hello","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"}];
```

I am trying to loop through the array and return an array of items group by the key "name" which will hold indexes of the items with same key.

expected result like below:

```
[
{bene: [0,2]},
{leg: [1,3]},
{hello: [4]}
]
```

I've put together the below but can't get it to work.

```
var obj = FinalArray.reduce(function(agg, item, index, f) {
  var name = item.name || ""
  var index = FinalArray.findIndex(item)
/*   var copy = [...item.jArray];
   */  if (!agg[name]) {
 
    agg[name] = []
  }
  agg[name].push(index)

  return agg;
}, {})
```

fairly new to using reduce and groupby. any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate an object of the names with their indexes with a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the original array, just pushing indexes into the array for each name.

If you then want an array of those values (I'm not sure this is a better structure), you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key value pairs and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) those into individual objects in an array

```js
var FinalArray = [
{"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"123"},"name":"bene","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
{"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"456"},"name":"leg","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
{"jArray":[{"Cd":"B"}],"Ref":{"docId":"123"},"name":"bene","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
{"jArray":[{"Cd":"B"}],"Ref":{"docId":"456"},"name":"leg","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
{"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"789"},"name":"hello","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"}];

var obj = FinalArray.reduce((acc, { name }, i) => {
  acc[name] = (acc[name] || []).concat([i])
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(obj)

objArray = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k] : v }))
console.log(objArray)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by just using two JavaScript methods [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) along with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Live Demo **:**

```js
// Input array
var FinalArray = [
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"123"},"name":"bene","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"456"},"name":"leg","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"B"}],"Ref":{"docId":"123"},"name":"bene","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"B"}],"Ref":{"docId":"456"},"name":"leg","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"789"},"name":"hello","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"}
];

const resObj = {};
const output = [];

// creating a object with the required key: values.
FinalArray.forEach((obj, index) => {
  resObj[obj.name] ? resObj[obj.name].push(index) : resObj[obj.name] = [index];
});

// destructuring the object into an array of objects.
Object.keys(resObj).forEach(key => {
    output.push({
    [key]: resObj[key]
  })
});

// final output
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP might try a combination of ...

- a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach which straightforwardly creates and collects an index/map of `name` based groups where the group key resemble an iterated item's `name` key, and the group value is an array of same `name`-value item-indices.
- and a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping of the reduced object's [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/).

```js
const finalArray = [
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"123"},"name":"bene","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"456"},"name":"leg","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"B"}],"Ref":{"docId":"123"},"name":"bene","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"B"}],"Ref":{"docId":"456"},"name":"leg","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"789"},"name":"hello","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
];

console.log(
  'index/map based result ...',
  finalArray
    .reduce((groups, { name }, idx) => {

      (groups[name] ??= []).push(idx);
      return groups;
      
    }, {})
);
console.log(
  "OP's expected result ...",
  Object
    .entries(
      finalArray
        .reduce((groups, { name }, idx) => {

          (groups[name] ??= []).push(idx);
          return groups;

        }, {})
    )
    .map(([key, value]) => ({ [ key ]: value }))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach was to solely stick to `reduce`, where one then needs to implement a reducer function which achieves everything in a single run and does both ...

- keeping track of the (to be) generated groups and the (to be) collected indices
- and aggregating the final `result` of the `reduce` method's accumulator/collector object which gets passed as the method's 2nd parameter ... its [`initialValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters).

```js
const finalArray = [
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"123"},"name":"bene","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"456"},"name":"leg","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"B"}],"Ref":{"docId":"123"},"name":"bene","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"B"}],"Ref":{"docId":"456"},"name":"leg","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
  {"jArray":[{"Cd":"A"}],"Ref":{"docId":"789"},"name":"hello","check1":false,"check2":false,"check3":false,"check4":false,"id":"0001"},
];

const { result } = finalArray
  .reduce(({ result = [], groups = {} }, { name }, idx) => {

    let group = groups[name];
    if (!group) {

      group = groups[name] = { [ name ]: [] };
      result.push(group);
    }
    group[name].push(idx)

    return { result, groups };

  }, { result: [] });

console.log({ result });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```